# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type audio/mpeg error in Chrome console preventing sounds from playing

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm creating a dumb fun little website that plays a random meme sound when a button is clicked. I was getting mixed content errors so I changed all my links to https. However, now when I click the button that should make the sounds play, the javascript file is loaded but the sound won't play. In the console the error says: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type audio/mpeg. The sounds don't play in Chrome but work fine in Firefox. How can I get the sounds to play in Chrome?

Here's the website so you can test it yourself: dankmemesoundboard.com

Comment: works on my machine... (Win 10, Chrome 76.0.3809.132)

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why Chrome should interpret the files as Documents.
Could be a bug...
But if you use the Audio API it doesn't.

```js
var audio = null;
function playRandomSound(){
    let r = randomNr(1,135);
    if(audio && audio.pause) audio.pause();
    audio = new Audio("/Sounds/" + r + ".mp3");
    audio.play();
}

function randomNr(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```